# Thymeleaf: conditional expression is not evaluated

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

In my current spring project, one of the views have the following thymeleaf code:

```
  <div class="input-group" th:each="item : ${role}" th:id="${item.getId()}">
    <span class="input-group-addon" th:with="possui = 'not'">
      <span th:each="item2 : ${usuario.getRole()}" th:if="${item.getId() == item2.getId()}" th:with="possui = 'yes'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-check" th:id="icon__${item.getId()}__" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span th:if="possui == 'not'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked" th:id="icon__${item.getId()}__" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </span>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" th:value="${item.getNome()}" disabled="disabled"/>

    <span class="input-group-btn">
      <button class="btn btn-default" th:attr="data-id=${item.getId()}" type="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
```

in the first block from `input-group` (the one with the class `input-group-addon`), should be displayed the checked icon if the user has the role, or the unchecked icon if the user hasn't. But with the code above, only the checked icon is displayed.

Anyone can see what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2):

```
<span th:if="possui == 'not'" class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked" th:id="icon__${item.getId()}__" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

should be

```
<span th:if="${possui == 'not'}" class="glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked" th:id="icon__${item.getId()}__" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Notice the `${possui == 'not'}`

Tip: You `${item.getId()}`, you can use `${item.id}`

Comment: with this sugestion, the checked icon is displayed correctly, but the unchecked icon is displayed for all the items of the list.

Comment: @KleberMota I have only reviewed your code for syntax, such complex condition should not be implemented on the front side, put it on java code. it will be more clear